# How do I attach to Skype using Skype4Java?

Tags: skype, skype4java

I am getting the following exception when trying to run the MakeCall example code:

```
com.skype.NotAttachedException
    at com.skype.Utils.convertToSkypeException(Utils.java:36)
    at com.skype.Skype.setDebug(Skype.java:116)
    at com.skype.sample.MakeCall.main(MakeCall.java:26)
Caused by: com.skype.connector.NotAttachedException
    at com.skype.connector.Connector.assureAttached(Connector.java:580)
    at com.skype.connector.Connector.addConnectorListener(Connector.java:604)
    at com.skype.connector.Connector.addConnectorListener(Connector.java:591)
    at com.skype.connector.Connector.setDebug(Connector.java:209)
    at com.skype.Skype.setDebug(Skype.java:114)
    ... 1 more
```

Now, I have not provided any sort of API credentials, so I kind of expect it to fail.  My question then, is how do I provide whatever credentials necessary to attach my connector?  The documentation on Skype4Java seems pretty slim.

After not getting any tips here, I have cross-posted this question on the [Skype community forum](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=397881) as well.

Comment: In which OS are you getting this exception? My application ran fine in Windows and Ubuntu but am seeing the same error in mac OS X

Comment: Yeah, I was seeing this in OS X.

Comment: @Ravi, no, I never did get this to work.  I ended up going a different route altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Had same thing, went on Skype->Options->Advance->Manage Other Programs access to Skype...selected
 Java.exe from the list and set option to allow. Working perfect now.

Comment: Its not working with Skype 7.26.0.101, the option is grayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the dbus dependency installed, then make sure to start skype on the command line with the "--use-system-dbus".

https://developer.skype.com/Docs/ApiDoc/src#Linux

Once skype is running and you then start the java program, you'll be prompted to allow your java program to access skype.